# Exception handling during the multiple asynchronous method call is not working

Tags: c#, multithreading, mqtt

I am generating more than 100 messages per second and sending these messages in separate thread. When connection is down, I want to catch the exception in caller. Since all my messages are sent asynchronous, I am not able to catch the exceptions.

Here is the `DispatcherTimer` code which calls the `dispatcherTimer_Tick` method

```
dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);


private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        item = "some generated message";
        Task.Run(() => SendMessage(item));                  
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Here is the `SendMessage` code. I have made change by reading Based on: [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), BUT it's not working

```
private async static Task SendMessage(string message)
{
    try
    {
        (MQTT.RunAsync(message.ToString(), topic)).Wait();                
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)    
    {
        // Exceptions are not getting cought here
    }
}
```

**Definition of MQTT.RunAsync**

```
public static async Task RunAsync(string message)
{
    var mqttClient = factory.CreateMqttClient()               
    try
    {
        await mqttClient.ConnectAsync(options);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {

    }
}
```

And

```
Task<MqttClientConnectResult> ConnectAsync(IMqttClientOptions options)
```

**Updated Question**

My `RunAsync` is first trying to connect and if success then it sends the message. so I can't write `return` while connection check.

```
 public Task RunAsync(string message, string topicName)
    {

            this.mqttClient.ConnectAsync(this.options);
            mqttClient.SubscribeAsync(new TopicFilterBuilder().WithTopic(this._topicname).WithExactlyOnceQoS().Build());
            var applicationMessage = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder().WithTopic(this._topicname)
               .WithPayload(message).WithAtLeastOnceQoS().Build();

            if (stopSending == false)
            {
                return mqttClient.PublishAsync(applicationMessage);
            }
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried throwing the exception from RunAsync in MQTT.RunAsync?

Comment: Yes, that breaks the applications. i wrote, Throw exception.

Comment: I feel AppDomain.UnhandledException Event is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Event handlers are an exception where `async void` is allowed

```
private async void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        item = "some generated message";
        await SendMessage(item);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //...handle exception
    }
}
```

Plus you appear to be consuming the exception any way as it is already being caught further down the stack.

Try to keep the code async all the way through and not mix blocking calls like `.Wait()` or `.Result`

```
private static Task SendMessage(string message) {
    return MQTT.RunAsync(message, topic);
}

public static async Task RunAsync(string message, string topicName) {
    await this.mqttClient.ConnectAsync(this.options);
    var topicFilter = new TopicFilterBuilder().WithTopic(this._topicname)
        .WithExactlyOnceQoS().Build();
    await mqttClient.SubscribeAsync(topicFilter);
    var applicationMessage = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder().WithTopic(this._topicname)
       .WithPayload(message).WithAtLeastOnceQoS().Build();

    if (stopSending == false) {
        await mqttClient.PublishAsync(applicationMessage);
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks good, but my RunAsync is not simple. I have put entire RunAsync method now in question. I can not use "return" inside RunAsync for connection check. even connection check also might throw exception

Comment: still it's not throwing exception!

Comment: Resolved. we should not put try catch :) and need to use TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException handler :)